# How to fix "data("url") is undefined" issue in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, undefined, sweetalert2

data("url") return undefined

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    $(".removeBtn").click((e) => {

        var $data_url = $(this).data("url");

        console.log($data_url); //It return undefined

        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Are you sure?',
            text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.value) {
                window.location.href = $data_url;
            }
        })
    })
})
```

```
<button data-url="<?php echo base_url("product/deleteProduct/$product->id"); ?>" class="btn btn-outline btn-danger removeBtn">Remove</button>
```

Comment: Can you also add your html?

Comment: You're using an arrow function, which doesn't scope `this`. If you want `this` to refer to the clicked element, then you need to use a normal anonymous function - `$(".removeBtn").click( function() { ... } );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `this` does not reference the element you think it does.

(This is due to the arrow function, which doesn't scope `this`)

Instead you should use `e.target` here to get the clicked element

```js
$(document).ready(() =>{ $(".removeBtn").click((e) =>{

    var $data_url = $(e.target).data("url");

    console.log($data_url); //It return undefined

})

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-url="something" class="btn btn-outline btn-danger removeBtn">Remove</button>
```

NOTE: the value of `data-url` is "*something*", so this snippet will just print the value e.g. "*something*" to the console